# Managing multiple SignalR connections in a single page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr

[I'm experiencing intermittent signalr connection problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY26E.png)

sometimes it fails, sometimes it doesn't...

Here is the setup...

I have a list of orders, each order has a unique signalr connection. Currently there are 230 orders on a single page. The purpose of having a signalr connection is so users can see any real time updates on each order (who is viewing, editing, etc). I've decided to have a separate connection for each order so that I don't have to manage the order that is currently being viewed, edited, etc. So far, for the orders that have successfully connected, the updates are correct and smooth.

[Here is my list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2ec2.png) with a sample of another user viewing an order (a photo of that user is being shown)

Here is my code that connects to the signalr hubs

```
crimeassure.factory('hubProxy', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

  function hubProxyFactory(hubName) {

      var _hubConnection = $.hubConnection();
      _hubConnection.logging = true;
      var _hubProxy = _hubConnection.createHubProxy(hubName);

      return {
          on: function (eventName, callback, failCallback) {
              _hubProxy.on(eventName, function (result) {
                  $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                      if (callback) {
                          callback(result);
                      }
                  });                     
              })
          },
          invoke: function (methodName, data) {
              _hubProxy.invoke(methodName, data)
              .done(function (result) {
                  //$rootScope.$apply(function () {
                  //    if (callback) {
                  //        callback(result);
                  //    }
                  //});
              });
          },
          start: function (successCallback, failCallback) {                  
              _hubConnection.start({ transport: 'webSockets' }).done(successCallback).fail(failCallback);
          },              
          hubConnection: _hubConnection,

      };
  };

  return hubProxyFactory;
```

}]);

```
crimeassure.directive('componentLiveUpdates', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            componentId: '=',               
        },
        templateUrl: '/scripts/templates/directive-templates/component-live-updates.html',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        controller: ["$scope", "$rootScope", "appData", "hubProxy",
            function componentLiveUpdates($scope, $rootScope, appData, hubProxy) {
                var vm = (this);
                var user = appData.getCurrentUser();
                vm.componentActivity = [];

                var reQueueHub = hubProxy('researcherExpressQueueHub');

                var componentActivityChanged = function (component) {
                    if (component.ActivityValue === 'ComponentModalClose') {
                        var idx = vm.componentActivity.indexOf(component);
                        vm.componentActivity.splice(idx, 1);
                    }

                    if (component.ActivityValue === 'ComponentModalOpen') {
                        vm.componentActivity.push(component);
                    }
                }

                var successCallback = function () {
                    console.log('connected to signalR, connection ID =' + reQueueHub.hubConnection.id + '--' + vm.componentId);
                    reQueueHub.invoke('joinGroup', vm.componentId);

                    $rootScope.reQueueHubs.push({
                        ComponentId: vm.componentId,
                        Hub: reQueueHub
                    });
                }

                var failCallback = function (e) {
                    console.log('Error connecting to signalR = ' + vm.componentId);
                    console.log(e);

                    //startHubConnection();
                }

                var startHubConnection = function () {
                    reQueueHub.start(successCallback, failCallback);
                }

                var initialize = function () {
                    reQueueHub.on('updateComponentActivity', componentActivityChanged);

                    startHubConnection();
                }

                initialize();
            }],
    }
});
```

and here is my hub class

```
public class ResearcherExpressQueueHub : Hub
{

    public void UpdateComponentActivity(ComponentItem item)
    {
        Clients.Group(item.ComponentId.ToString()).updateComponentActivity(item);
    }

    public void ComponentModalOpen(ComponentItem item)
    {
        item.Activity = ComponentActivity.ComponentModalOpen;
        Clients.Group(item.ComponentId.ToString()).updateComponentActivity(item);
    }

    public void ComponentModalClose(ComponentItem item)
    {
        item.Activity = ComponentActivity.ComponentModalClose;
        Clients.Group(item.ComponentId.ToString()).updateComponentActivity(item);
    }

    public Task JoinGroup(string componentId)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, componentId);
    }

    public Task LeaveGroup(string componentId)
    {
        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, componentId);
    }
}
```

so my questions are,

1. Why am i experiencing a disconnect "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established"
2. Is my approach the best way to approach this type of requirement?

Comment: Where's the code that shows how you're connecting? As it is, there is not enough information here to even begin to reproduce the problem.

Comment: my apologies.. I just edited the question and uploaded a screenshot

Comment: All code should be in the question itself. Screenshots are also discouraged

Comment: thanks for the advice, it's been long since I've been using stackoverflow :D I've updated the question now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use grouping mechanisme of signalr and NOT create multiple connections for your usecase!**

There are limitations from IIS and also from browsers. Some browser have a limit of 4 or 5 paralell connections. You can test it by yourself by opening multiple different browsers.

**Details about grouping:**

Working with groups in signalr is really simple. Details you will find here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups

Comment: I am already utilizing grouping by the order id. Are you suggesting that I'll have a single connection? And group by... order id or by user?

Comment: @AjGrandeza: For me is you use case not clear in each detail. Can you please explain more details which information you like to send the client. We can chat for short.... would be easier

Comment: @AjGrandeza: From my point of view I would create it like the following. In the case the page initial loads, the clients makes a getAllOrders and subcribes to events (OrderAdded, OrderEdited, OrderRemoved). In the eventhandlers you can update your orderlist according the events. There is no grouping required. But I not shure if Inderstand you requirements correct

Comment: you seem to have understood my requirements. but I'm having another problem with the grouping... I grouped them with order id, so any updates on that order will reflect only on that order... now that I have a single connection, this single connection now has multiple subscriptions to different groups (because there are many orders).. now that's the setup and every order is getting the updates from other orders...

Comment: How many changes ob orders do you have in 1 minute? I suggest that you need no grouping...

Comment: hmmm but possibly around a hundred, more or less

Comment: Ok. I try to understand you better. You wrote: "now that I have a single connection, this single connection now has multiple subscriptions to different groups (because there are many orders).." Whats not good with that?

Comment: I just realized that you correct. heh sorry bout that.. I'll mark this as an answer. Followed your advice, single connection with no groupings. Works fine now. Thanks!